# ATmega328p bootloader issue : [avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding]

Tags: atmega328, bootloader

I am using an arduino uno board and have placed the new ATmega328chip in the socket as a simple setup as mentioned in [Minicore installation instructions](https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore). However, I am unable to burn the bootloader. I am using your minicore and selected the ATmega328 chip. I have tried using 8MHz internal crystal as well as 16 MHz external crystal but get the same error. I even tried using a different ATmega328p but the result was same. Here is the output:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20201216
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\MiniCore\hardware\avr\2.1.2/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Error while burning bootloader.
```

Before trying this Minicore option I also tried different tutorials which ask for external crystal and extra capacitors. It's been two days I am trying to make it work but sadly haven't managed it yet. Initially I suspected a faulty ATmega but even three other chips result in the same error or device signature error.

Here are the other connections I have used:

[image: Serial connection]

[image: FTDI/UART connection]

Could you please help me fix it? Thanks

Comment: Do you *have* an STK500 Version 1 programmer that you're using to burn the bootloader? Or are you just plugging the Arduino into USB and praying that something miraculously happens?

Comment: I don't have that programmer but an AVR asp programmer. For minimal setup I thought I just need to replace the new ATmega in the socket and then then burn the bootloader by plugging the arduino into usb. I didn't even pray though :) May be I didn't understand the minimal setup correctly.

Comment: I did also try with the FTDI/UART connection and the ISP to burn the bootloader but was getting a signature error.

Comment: I have edited original post with the connection sketches

Comment: To program the bootloader you need either a hardware programmer or a working Arduino to use as a programmer. But I am confused (and likely you are too). You say you put the chip in the socket then show us a circuit with a breadboard...

Comment: Here is sequence of what I have tried so far. First I tried to burn the bootloader with the ATmega328p & other components on a breadboard following the two different connection schemes shown above.  I got error "avrdude: Yikes! Invalid device signature. Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override this check." At last I simply replaced the ATmega on my working uno board to burn the bootloader.

Comment: The former is what you need to do, not the latter. Set it up on a breadboard again and try various tutorials again. Many miss out disabling the Arduino's auto serial reset which you have to do for it to work.

Comment: I started a new with clean wiring and tried the tutorial on the arduino website and it does use a pullup resistor on the reset pin. It worked :) Thanks for the pointer

Comment: you can't burn bootloader into ATmega by putting it on Uno. even if the ATmega is on Uno you have to use a programmer (or other Arduino as programmer with Arduino as ISP sketch)

Comment: @Juraj yeah I misunderstood one of the tutorial. I thought by just placing it on the uno board socket I wouldn't need any external circuitry like caps, resistors and the crystal. Also I would be able to use the serial to usb connection on the board to burn the bootloader. But it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the bootloader using either an working Arduino or a hardware programmer.

There is one step that many many tutorials on this subject miss out (and both the circuits you show have missed it out), and that is to disable the automatic reset of the programming Arduino.  That can be done a number of ways:

- Add a low-value pullup resistor to RESET
- Add a high-value capacitor between RESET and GND
- Cut the "RESET-EN" trace on the underside of the board

Once the bootloader is installed in this way you can then put the chip into an Arduino and program it through USB, or connect it to a USB to UART adapter and program it through that.

Comment: I used the first method. However, even with a 10K resistor it worked